# mysql update data using 3 table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I did own custom table in wordpress base, and now i need update the table using data from wopdpress's tables (thundbail link)

Here select query

```
SELECT p.post_parent, guid
  FROM wp_postmeta AS pm
 INNER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
 WHERE pm.post_id = 1552
   AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
 ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Answer:
post_parent (fullproducts = postid) | guid (fullproducts = image)

1552 | URL

---

I tryed this  code for update this table

```
UPDATE full_products, wp_postmeta AS pm
SET full_products.image = wp_postmeta.guid
 INNER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 
 WHERE pm.post_id = full_products.postid 
 AND pm.post_id = 1552
   AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
 ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

But this query doesnt work. Could you check it?

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` in the `UPDATE` statement is in the wrong place; put it before the `SET` keyword, together with the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you used `UPDATE` with `INNER JOIN` have syntax error, the correct syntax is

```
UPDATE full_products a
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON a.postid = pm.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p 
ON pm.meta_value=p.ID
SET a.image = pm.guid
WHERE pm.post_id = 1552
AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
```

Comment: Please look to the correct select query, my update query can be verry incorrect. The recordo of image is in wp_posts, here you dont use this

Comment: THANK YOU!

With you help I got correct query

<code>
UPDATE full_products fp
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm
ON fp.postid = pm.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS p 
ON pm.meta_value=p.ID 

SET fp.image = p.guid
WHERE pm.post_id = 1552
AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
</code>

Comment: @user2421781 you welcome man, don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems